# Is a moderator considered as a normal user?

Tags: discussion, moderators, serial-voting

I'm asking because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124597/hey-i-just-lost-350-points-for-serial-upvoting-reversed)  by reading [Marc's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124599/163573) answer:

> *the emphasis is on a post, not a user.*

Does this automated process also apply to moderators, or are they protected from this?

I mean, what if a user started voting up of all the posts of a specific moderator, then what will be the scenario?

Comment: Moderators can't be considered as normal. They don't eat. They don't sleep. They only drink the blood of spammers.

Comment: Moderator is also like administrator. Moderator is to track daily activities of forum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

That should answer your answer

(translation: Moderators aren't exempt from vote fraud scripts, neither are we given any special treatment. We are as rate limited as other users and treated the same.)

Comment: 404 image not found

Comment: @Ian hm? Showing fine here.

Answer (score 4):

If you vote for too many of a moderator's posts in a short time period, the voter fraud script will reverse them, the same way they would be reversed for any other user.

Comment: Actually the thing is that *I'm one of the victim*

Comment: If I serially-voted your posts, they would be reversed during the next voter-fraud script run, just like any other user's serial voting.

Comment: You mean to say, `current fraud(triggers) + reserve fraud = demolition`, is it?

Comment: @hotveryspicy - If you're referring to the votes going to you that were invalidated yesterday, no moderator was involved in that. It was all due to one normal user.

Comment: @BradLarson Okay, but now what I'm wondering that Automated's algorithm may be sometimes prove to be wrong. If a specific user always post perfect answer with proper explanation then he must deserves upvote, isnt it?

Comment: @hotveryspicy: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156299

Answer (score 4):

Yes, mods will be considered as normal user in that case. Automated process will be same for everyone including moderators.